# Store sum in KTable<String, Integer>

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to count amount of envelopes from a topic. Transaction is in avro-format. I use [this example](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.2.2-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/SumLambdaExample.java) as a reference.

```
final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
final KStream<String, Transaction> transactionKStream = streamsBuilder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC);

final KStream<String, Integer> envelopes = transactionKStream.filter((k, v) -> v.getProduct().toString()
    .matches("C4|C5"))
    .map((k, v) -> KeyValue.pair("1", v.getAmount()));

final KTable<String, Integer> amount = envelopes
    .groupByKey()
    .reduce((v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);
```

I want to store the sum in the KTable<> but when I send data to the input-topic the consumer crashes with

`A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: java.lang.Integer). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.`

When KTable<> is commented out it runs fine. But don't sum amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupByKey()` makes use of the default serialisers:

> **`groupByKey()`**
>
> Group the records by their current key into a
>   KGroupedStream while preserving the original values and default
>   serializers and deserializers.

You either have to use `groupByKey(Serialized<K,V> serialized)` or `groupByKey(Grouped<K,V> grouped)`.

The following should do the trick:

```
final KTable<String, Integer> amount = envelopes
    .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Integer()))
    .reduce((v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);
```